# narrowing typescript 'shape.radius' is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, compiler-errors, undefined

```
interface Shape {
  kind: "circle" | "square",
  radius?: number,
  sideLength?: number
}

function getArea(shape: Shape): number | undefined {
  if (shape.kind === "circle" && Object.hasOwn(shape, "radius")) {
    // 'shape.radius' is possibly 'undefined'. ts(18048)
    return Math.PI * shape.radius**2;
  }
  else if (shape.kind === "square" && "sideLength" in shape) {
    // 'shape.sideLength' is possibly 'undefined'. ts(18048)
    return shape.sideLength**2;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

why am i getting 2 "is possibly 'undefined'" errors ? what is wrong with this logic? Didn't I already check that the property exists before returning the calculation?

i used Object.hasOwn and in but in both cases the error continued

Comment: Simply because it has the property doesn't guarantee it's not undefined; `{kind: 'circle', radius: undefined}` fulfills the interface contract and also passes `hasOwn`. As noted in the answer you actually want a discriminated union, but in general you will need to check explicitly for a value of `undefined` not just for the existence of the property. (unless setting `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` to true in your config)

Comment: You're not associating the different kind values with the optionality of their relevant properties. Define two types, one first Circle and one for square and then create a union type from them. `type Shape = Circle | Square`

Comment: pilchard thank you for your help I did what you said and it Worked for when I use "in" but when I use "Object.hasOwn" it is not working and the error continues. now I really don't understand why? if I've already guaranteed that it can't be undefined and also that the object has the property, what am I doing wrong?


My tsconfig.json is:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "lib": ["ES2022"],
        "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions). You have to have a common property in your union members, which is also unique and can be used for identifying shapes.

```
type Shape =
  | {
      kind: 'circle';
      radius: number;
    }
  | {
      kind: 'square';
      sideLength: number;
    };
```

Converting `Shape` to this will resolve the errors.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0lAvAKClAPlA3hzQgawEsA7AEwC4oByAYxICd6AbCWgbgMKiYQokArgGcaZIQFsARhCbdeAXwI58vTKUo1aIgI5CETDgvUiSFCABkIZAObA44qbPk8oi7mgBmQsvWAkAPZkULYQwACCRggAFCKIkDTwSBAAlE4ycthQvhZe5BAUeAQkXlBxCRAAdJpFKPV0jCzstKnFvEbAQkwhALIIDlUACgCSUABUUPEpVfyCohOTAEwmilAQrCLQpeXTkDXkdQ06+oYcUABkF3RmFtZ2DrRQ5FOVbWqEnd0he9W3VjZ7HBFlAVgRlJgvj0cpQIPkyIVuMogA)